# realtek ethernet driver compilation failed with error "realtek: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I am compiling ethernet realtek driver explicitly with some debug prints enabled.I am able to compile the module, but not able to insert module.

I have some info here:

```
Output of uname -r:
root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# uname -r
4.11.0

Realtek ethernet Sources:
root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# ls
cscope.out  icmp  icmp2_recev  logs_kernel  Makefile  out  realtek.c  tags

Upon make,
realtek.ko module has created, but i was not able to load it.
```

Surprisingly,
    I figured out my Makefile is picking wrong sources while compiling.
    My requirement is to compile against current running kernel.

```
PWD:
root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# pwd
/home/vkalyanam/realtek

        MAKEFILE:
        root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# cat Makefile 
        KERNEL_SRC := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

    obj-m := realtek.o

    all:
        make -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) modules
    clean:
        make -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) clean

    Driver Compilation:

    root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# make
    make -C /lib/modules/4.11.0/build M=/home/vkalyanam/realtek modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vkalyanam/eudyptula/task2/linux'
      CC [M]  /home/vkalyanam/realtek/realtek.o
      Building modules, stage 2.
      MODPOST 1 modules
      CC      /home/vkalyanam/realtek/realtek.mod.o
      LD [M]  /home/vkalyanam/realtek/realtek.ko
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vkalyanam/eudyptula/task2/linux'
    root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# 

If you look closely,
==> 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vkalyanam/eudyptula/task2/linux'

Makefile is picking /home/vkalyanam/eudyptula/task2/linux source directory.

I don't understand how come this would pick that particular directory.

Here are my environment variables:

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vkalyanam/eudyptula/task2/linux'
root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek# printenv
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SUDO_USER=vkalyanam
SUDO_UID=1000
USERNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
PWD=/home/vkalyanam/realtek
LANG=en_IN
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
HOME=/home/vkalyanam
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
SUDO_GID=1000
DISPLAY=:0
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XAUTHORITY=/home/vkalyanam/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/realtek#
```